# What we commonly refer high definition as

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus

**What is the two word answer to the puzzle below?**

---

16777215+262709978263278+3435973836 = (4)

281474976710655+1240612796065921481376886589594988270+967140655691703339764940 = (12)

1208925819614629174706175+1240612796065921481376886589594988270+225179981368524 = (11)

65535+15658734+52428 = (11)

4294967295+262709978263278+13421772 = (10)

---

(4)+(12)+(11)+(11)+(10)= **(8)(6)**

---

Hint 1

> One of the three is a synonym, but overall this is just a regular puzzle.

Comment: Damn, got the first bit fairly quickly and been stumped ever since, very cool idea first idea though!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Keep going :) Try to include the rebus and knowledge tags somehow

Comment: I just noticed 65535 and now I'm suspicious…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This puzzle is about ...

> ... the five **[Platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid)**, which is also the overall two-word answer.

The first step ...

> ... is to write the long numbers in hexadecimal:
>
>               FFFFFF₁₆ +     EEEEEEEEEEEE₁₆ +         CCCCCCCC₁₆ = (4)
>         FFFFFFFFFFFF₁₆ + EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE₁₆ + CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC₁₆ = (12)
>     FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF₁₆ + EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE₁₆ +     CCCCCCCCCCCC₁₆ = (11)
>                 FFFF₁₆ +           EEEEEE₁₆ +             CCCC₁₆ = (11)
>             FFFFFFFF₁₆ +     EEEEEEEEEEEE₁₆ +           CCCCCC₁₆ = (10)
>
>  That's a bit repetitive, so let's clean that up:
>
>          6·F + 12·E +  8·C = (4)
>         12·F + 30·E + 20·C = (12)
>         20·F + 30·E + 12·C = (11)
>          4·F +  6·E +  4·C = (11)
>          8·F + 12·E +  6·C = (10)
>
>  (That's nonsense from a mathematical point of view, of course, but I'm applying the magic of the rebus tag here.)

What does that mean?

> Each line has a number of **F**s, **E**s and **C**s. Also, only certain numbers appear: 4, 6, 8, 12, 20 and 30.
>
>  It took me a while to see this, but the lines refer to the **Faces**, **Edges** and **Coordinates** (vertices) of the five Platonic solids:
>
>  **cube**: 6 faces, 12 edges,  8 vertices
>  **dodecahedron**: 12 faces, 30 edges, 20 vertices
>  **icosahedron**: 20 faces, 30 edges, 12 vertices
>  **tetrahedron**: 4 faces,  6 edges,  4 vertices
>  **octahedron**: 8 faces, 12 edges,  6 vertices
>
>  The numbers in parentheses are the letter enumerations for these words. The overall two-word answer has (8) and (6) letters: **Platonic solids**.
>
>  (The Platonic solids are the only five convex regular polyhedra, so that's what the "regular" in the hint refers to. "Vertex" requires a synonym that starts with one of the letters used for hexadecimal notation, but not E or F.)

Comment: Ahhh very nice, interesting bit of trivia too - the numbers in the puzzle are known as 'Brazilian Numbers' - numbers that are [repdigits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit) in another base

Comment: Well done! You got the correct answer. Just check the terms in row 2 and row 3 under "the first step". Everything else looks perfect!

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was an old draft, where I (well, the program I used) stopped at 64 bits ... `:(` (And I'm still missing a link to the title.)

Comment: No prob, looks good now.

Comment: Might be worth noting the pun in the hint...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: I know that I haven't explained the title. But I don't see the pun, I'm afraid.

Comment: If there's a pun in the title then I haven't seen it either (though I suspect there is one). I was referring to the _hint_, which says that "this is just a _regular_ puzzle".

Comment: Oh, I see. Reading comprehension is a bit hit and miss lately ...